# Meter fuse availability/substitution conundrum

Tags: multimeter, fuses, substitution

I own a Brymen BM235 multimeter, among other test instruments.  While it's a nice multimeter, I have one problem with it: the fuse for the mA jack is a Siba 7017240.0,4, and *nobody* even bothers with putting this part in their catalog, never mind stocking it.  (Octopart shows [no results at all](https://octopart.com/7017240.0.4-siba-67937551?r=sp&s=JkmztJM_RmiuwNAr9GNY5w).  That's how *bad* this situation is.)

However, the adjacent values (315mA and 500mA) in the Siba 7017240 line *are* stocked.  Given that my BM235 (interestingly enough) says 600mA on the front for the maximum current it can measure using the mA jack, which fuse (315mA or 500mA) should I substitute for the unobtanium 400mA fuse, or should I try to poke Brymen or the distributor I got the meter through about this little conundrum?  Or should I try to find a way to get Siba to point me at where I can get these in the USA? (It's the one fuse I don't have spares on-hand for at the moment -- even though I generally don't blow meter fuses to begin with, and haven't blown the one in the Brymen, I'd rather be prepared in this case.)

Comment: I don't think there's anything special about that particular fuse. Any HRC fuse with the same dimensions and capacity should work.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- I don't know of any true substitutes for the Siba 7017240 line -- the Littelfuse 508 comes close, but a) isn't available in 400mA (only 315mA and 500mA) and b) is only rated to 10kAIC@1kVAC/DC (while the Siba parts in question are rated to 30kAIC@1kVAC/DC minimum)

Answer (score 1):

[A thread on the EEVBlog](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/replacement-fuse-for-eevblog-bm235-dmm/) mentions that the SIBA 70 172 40 FF400mA Fuse Ultra Rapid FF 400mA 1000V DMM DMI fuse is available on eBay. And, in fact, a cursory search for *400mA FF* reveals that there are several offerings.

[image]

Comment: I was actually able to find a European distributor who carried it in the end (eBay is not a distributor in my book, although if it's a cal service type place selling them, your chances of getting the real deal are probably better than some random seller of junk)